# Java application fails to process a special file that comes in every Thursday evening, while Cassandra throws an error

Tags: java, cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

All different files are processing fine, but this file seems to be special.

The solution is to restart both the Cassandra Database, Java application and re-upload the file into the S3 bucket for processing. Then the same file is processed correctly.

Right now, we're restarting the Java application and Cassandra database every Friday morning. We're suspecting accumulation of something to be a possible root cause of the problem, as the file is processed perfectly fine after a complete restart.

This is a screenshot of the error in Cassandra:

[image]

We're using Cassandra as a backend for Akka Persistence.

So a failure to ingest the file only happens when the cluster has been up for some time. I don't have a failure to ingest, if it's done soon after cluster start.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You're trying to slurp a 500MB+ file into memory, and presumably after the application has been running your memory is fragmented enough (or there's just enough accumulated) for that to be a problem. Give it more memory, bypass this check, or otherwise Do Your Thing.

Comment: We have already doubled our memory sizes a week ago, but the same error occurred again. The current values are MAX_HEAP_SIZE 8192M and HEAP_NEWSIZE 1024M. How would I bypass this check?

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not an `ERROR`, it's an `INFO`.  Secondly, it's telling you that you're writing into cache faster than the cache can be recycled.  If you're not seeing any negative effects (data loss, stale replicas, etc), I wouldn't sweat this.  Hence, the `INFO` and not `ERROR`.

If you are and you have some spare non-heap RAM on the nodes, you could try increasing `file_cache_size_in_mb`.  It defaults to 512MB, so you could try doubling that and see if it helps.

> we're restarting the Java application and Cassandra database every Friday morning

Also, there's nothing to really gain by restarting Cassandra on a regular basis.  Unless you're running it on a Windows machine (seriously hope you are not), you're really not helping anything by doing this.  My team supports high write throughput nodes that run for months, and are only restarted for security patching.